# Get column values from a table with multiple where criteria such as areas

Tags: sql

I'm trying to loop through a selection of areas to get the column value of all records that meet the criteria in selected areas for example Durban;Johannesburg;Chartwell . I need to populate a datatable as the datasource of a listbox.
From my searching I came up with the following MS SQL query using While. I also have the same issue with Cursors (used for the first time)

```
    SELECT value INTO #AreaTemp FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Areas,';')
    WHERE TRIM(value)<>''

    -- loop through each area
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM #AreaTemp)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @SrchArea nvarchar(50)
    SELECT @SrchArea = (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM #AreaTemp)
        SELECT Competitor_Idx, PartProfilePath
        FROM tblCompetitors
        WHERE Address_Details LIKE '%' + @SrchArea + '%' And dbo.AGE(Date_of_Birth) between @Age1 and @Age2 And Male = @Male And DATALENGTH(PartProfilePath) > 0
    DELETE FROM #AreaTemp WHERE value = @SrchArea
    END
```

The output is as per the attached image. What do I need to do to get all the matched records in one result to set as datasource for the datatable? Any guidance much appreciated

I also tried this method & got the same output so now I'm stuck going forward

```
    SELECT value INTO #AreaTemp FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Areas,';')
    WHERE TRIM(value)<>''

    DECLARE @value nvarchar(Max)
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT value FROM #AreaTemp 

    OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            SELECT Competitor_Idx, PartProfilePath
            FROM tblCompetitors
            WHERE Address_Details LIKE '%' + @value + '%' And dbo.AGE(Date_of_Birth) between @Age1 and @Age2 And Male = @Male And DATALENGTH(PartProfilePath) > 0
       
            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value 
        END
```

Comment: Please include more sample data and schema of the table.  Not enough to go on by looking at the question.

Comment: What are you doing with the result? From this code sample, it's not clear to me if/why you need a loop and can't just join `tblCompetitors` to `string_split(@Areas,';')`.

Comment: @EdmCoff the tblCompetitors field Address_Details is a full street address whereas the area in the string_split(@Areas,';') is just the suburb or town. As mentioned the result will be the datasource of a datatable. Currently I only get the results of the first area from the split being loaded to the datatable. The results when running the query is a seperate result list for each area. I need all the results for all the areas in one result list so the lsitbox I want to populate will have all the PartProfilePath's that meet the criteria

Comment: My question is why you are not just doing this in a single query. Why are you looping over a query that only does one at a time? I'm wondering why you can't do something like: https://dbfiddle.uk/fCIxdx3g

Comment: @EdmCoff You're a star. I'll be reading up more on Cross-Apply. You can teach an old dog new tricks as I continue to learn new techniques. This gives me the result I'm looking for. Thank you so much. Don't know how to indicate this as an answer to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EdmCoff, the following was the solution

```
DECLARE @Areas nvarchar(max) = 'Alberton;Chartwell', @Age1 int = 15, @Age2 int = 30, @Male bit = 0
```

SELECT value INTO #AreaTemp FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Areas,';')
WHERE TRIM(value)<>''
SELECT Competitor_Idx, PartProfilePath
FROM tblCompetitors CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@Areas,';')
WHERE Address_Details LIKE '%' + value + '%' And dbo.AGE(Date_of_Birth) between @Age1 and @Age2 And Male = @Male And DATALENGTH(PartProfilePath) > 0